# After upgrade from Dynamics CRM 2011 to CRm 2016 experiencing weird issue with forms and plugins

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

Client company just upgraded to 2016 from 2011. I've been testing the plugins to make sure they all still function and I've finally (after much frustration) figured out what is happening, but no idea why or how to resolve this.

I have several plugins and they all function exactly as expected - as long as the updates to the data are not run through the forms.

Let me explain:

I have plugins (Synchronous) that trigger on a change to a field. If the field is changed via a workflow, or some other coded process, everything runs just fine.

But when I update the field on the form it's self. It fails with a very generic error (below).

I support a couple of other clients already on 2016, and I'm not experiencing this same problem. So I'm not even sure where to begin. I've been going crazy here the last couple of days to check the code. But it only happens when updating the field on the form. Every other method of updating the data that I have tested works with no errors.

I also have another issue. When the field is updated (through a test workflow), it runs and updates a child record. The child record then has a workflow that runs to deactivate the record. The workflow says it ran and deactivated the record, but it never deactivates).

Anyway. if ANYONE has ANY idea at all about what could be causing this. I would love to hear it. I'm at my wits end on this.

Thank you in advance.

I've tested the code and had it run successfully, as long as I don't update the field through the form. To test this I created some test workflows that update the data, they successfully run and the plugins fire off with no problems.

```
EntityReference contact =    
(EntityReference)preImageEntity.Attributes["ipmahr_contact"];

QueryExpression cn = new QueryExpression("ipmahr_recertification");
cn.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("ipmahr_contact", "statecode");
cn.Criteria.AddCondition("ipmahr_contact", ConditionOperator.Equal,  
contact.Id);
cn.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 0);

EntityCollection results1 = server.RetrieveMultiple(cn);

if (results1.Entities.Count > 0)
     foreach (Entity a in results1.Entities)
     {
      a.Attributes["ipmahr_deactivaterecertificationrecord"] =   true;
         server.Update(a);
     }
```

The code is pretty straightforward in most cases, and works fine as long as things aren't updated on the form.

Here is the error: Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: #595EB751 (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault)., Correlation Id: fd1a79ca-c846-407b-b578-ac9207d6dd0e, Initiating User: 274d55dc-3f4d-e811-b30f-0050569142af Exiting Recertifications.Main.DeactivateUsedRecertificationsonEndDateChange.Execute(), Correlation Id: fd1a79ca-c846-407b-b578-ac9207d6dd0e, Initiating User: 274d55dc-3f4d-e811-b30f-0050569142af

---

New information. I have found that not all the plugins I've written have an issue on this server. This is good. But I also found that there is a commonality on those plugins that do fail.

Any plugin using a Query Expression fails with the generic error. Adding robust error checking didn't show anything (once error checking was added, it just didn't run anything, and didn't produce any errors in the logs). Trace logs didn't show anything significant either.

So now I'm wondering if there is something in the way the Query Expression is formatted, or if there is an issue with the SQL. I mention SQL because I found this morning that if I create fields too fast, I get a generic SQL error. Wait a minute and I can create new fields without a problem.

Comment: Can you show your error handling?  Does an empty plugin work?

Comment: Empty plugin, that doesn't fire anything works. When the field is updated by a workflow, the plugin works. The only time it fails is when the field is updated through a form (doesn't matter which form. I even created a form to make sure no javascript was set up to run). 

I'm updating my error handling this weekend, so I don't have anything for you on that right now. I have 3 clients on this particular version through the same vendor, and I don't have any issues with the other 2 clients. Only on this most recent upgrade.

Comment: Sounds like you have something messed up with your IIS process.  I'm guess these are not sandboxed?

Comment: Daryl, I agree with you that something is messed up. One thing I found today was the security roles were all messed up for a lot of people. But I couldn't narrow it down to anything specific, just a lot of missing permissions. IIS hadn't occurred to me. (I don't have access to the servers, this is through a hosted vendor). But it gives me another avenue to dig into for them. 

I appreciate.

The plugins are sandboxed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it likely that this plugin is not actually failing based on the error you are receiving and the fact that it happens conditionally. More likely, your server.Update(a); call is resulting in a failure within a secondary plugin or workflow action triggered by update of the Recertification record.
- Comment out that line and verify that the plugin works
- See if you can reproduce a failure by directly updating that field on the Recertification record
- Review plugin/workflows running against the Recertification entity

Most likely this has one of the following root causes:
- A security issue based on different executing users between the form update or workflow update 
- Other tangential fields are being updated by one or the other of those two methods which subsequently cause different behavior in a secondary plugin/workflow

Comment: Zach. Thank you. I've checked into this a little bit. But not as deep as I need to. What I'm doing, mostly, right now is to put in some workarounds to get the code up and running. Not super happy with having to do the workarounds. But the client needs this functioning, so I have to do it. 

Once I get it all up again, I'm going to do a couple of more tests like you suggested.